# Number of times above a linear boundary for a finite variance random walk

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk

I consider a random walk $(S_n)$ with mean zero and finite variance, and $\epsilon>0$. Is it true that

$$ \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} 1_{S_n>n\epsilon}\right] < +\infty \quad ? $$

If no, is it true if we add the hypothesis $\mathbb{E}\left(|S_1|^{2+\delta}\right)<+\infty$ ?

Comment: it's true with 2nd moments, not fewer, and is known as hsu-robbins or hsu-robbins-erdos, and is from around 1952

Comment: Thank you for the reference, this is exactly what I needed.